# Position div at the bottom with scrollable sibling above

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky-footer

```html
<div class="menu__content" style="max-height: 100px; min-width: 410px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <div class="card" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="list">
    <div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>b</div>
            <div>b</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>c</div>
            <div>c</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>d</div>
            <div>d</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="results">
   <a>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>6 results</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have this structure

```
<div class="menu__content" style="max-height: 300px; min-width: 410px;">
    <div class="card" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="list">
    <div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>b</div>
            <div>b</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>c</div>
            <div>c</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>d</div>
            <div>d</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="results">
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>6 results</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the elements inside `<div class="list">` are in a scrollable window and I would like the `<div class="results">` to be as a sticky bottom but cant figure out how to position this correctly.
Currently it just scrolls down with the rest of the items.
What is the correct css in this case?
I added a snippet to show the exact problem

Comment: Please coul dyou show your relevant CSS and make your code into a snippet we can run. Also what is it you want to stick to the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.list {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 180px;
}
.results {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>
  <div>13</div>
  <div>14</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>16</div>
  <div class="results">total results: 16</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [source article](https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46) which explains how to use `position: sticky;`

Comment: my structure is different, I cant control it - its a third party controller that I can edit to some extent

Answer (score 0):

Your structure may be different, but the CSS you need is exactly what I posted.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.list {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.results {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu__content" style="max-height: 100px; min-width: 410px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <div class="card" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="list">
    <div>
   <a class="list__tile list__tile--link">
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>a</div>
            <div>a</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>b</div>
            <div>b</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>c</div>
            <div>c</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
<div>
   <a>
      <div>
         <div>
            <div>d</div>
            <div>d</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="results">
   <a>
   <div>
      <div>
         <div>6 results</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```